# React native fetch... Explain it like I'm 5

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, iterator, fetch

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=5"); // Replace this with the API call to the JSON results of what you need for your app.
    const json = await response.json(); 
    this.setState({ data: json.results }); // for the randomuser json result, the format says the data is inside results section of the json.
  };
```

So, I have this code in my App.js file for React Native. The randomuser.me is a website that just gives you random users. Using it as a test URL right now. I don't really understand what the code is doing enough to be able to use it for other parts of my project. I was able to successfully display the 5 user results but now I want to access them again and iterate through the data attribute of the state.

tldr; Can I just access the data I got from the fetch in a for loop using data[i]? Please advise. I want to see if user input matches any of the items in the response that is stored in data attribute of state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the thign that you just did, that is fetch. You retrieve data from the internet.
"https://randomuser.me/api?results=5" is an API, there is lot of different API's, and each one has it´s own way to retrieve data from. if you put "https://randomuser.me/api?results=5" in your browser, you are gonna see a JSON, some API's store data in JSON, others in an array format.
In this case, the JSON, has just one child, 'results', thats why you store "json.results".

That´s fetch. The thing that you want to do is just javascript.
Store json.results in a variable
then iterate over it

```
 var Results = json.results //store it in a variable
    for(var i = 0;i<Object.keys(Results).length;i++){ //iterate
      var CurrentUser = Results[Object.keys(Results)[i]] // i use this because some JSOn have random keys
      if(CurrentUser.gender==='male'){//if you meet a condition
      //do whatever you want
      }

}
```

you can also use ".map" if it´s an array

Comment: Use `camelCase` instead of `TitleCase` for variable names, otherwise it looks like you're working with constructors or classes instead of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I put the variables in camelCase. I put this for loop in a handler that I call onpress in the render() part of the main component App.js. The handler is being called but it never goes into the loop as per the console.log statement. When I console.log the value of what Results is in your code, I see it start with Array. Perhaps it could be an Array? Maybe this is because I set the object as data[] with the square brackets?

Comment: You are correct, in this case results is an array of objects.

Comment: and i´ve forgotten to put ".length" after the Object.keys() . i´m really sorry, the problem is fixed now. That for loop iteration should work for both an array and a json.